# Mobile users redirected to a different page on login unless linked to another post

Tags: login

I have a responsive website which is accessed via login only. All pages can be accessed via mobile / desktop it's just we thought having a different page for mobile users was more appropriate.

I previously asked to redirect mobile users to a different landing page and got this answer (which works very well):

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function($to, $request, $user)
{
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) $to = home_url().'/mobile-news';

    return $to;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```

Currently if a user is linked to a news article (e.g. site.com/exciting-news-article) they will be met with the login page (this is normal) however once they log in the redirect request is ignored in favour of (site.com/mobile-news) page.

I need to adapt this so that if they're linked to a specific news item they'll go there instead of the mobile-news page.

I've been trying different solutions but it just seems to ignore completely. This is what I currently have and it's not working correctly:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function($to, $request, $user)
{
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
      if ($_GET['redirect_to'] != '') {
          $to = $_GET['redirect_to'];

      }
      else {
          $to =  home_url().'/mobile-news';
      }
    }
    return $to;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```

Has anyone come across this problem before - I'm not sure where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function($to, $request, $user)
{
    if ( wp_is_mobile() && $request == null ) {
        return home_url().'/mobile-news';
    }
    return $to;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```

Not tested, but should work.

**Note:** using a URL like this one `home_url().'/mobile-news'` is not a good idea, I think.

Use `get_permalink( $post_id )` instead. Where `$post_id` is the ID of `home_url().'/mobile-news'` page. Because, if the slug of that page somehow got changed, visitors will see a 404 page!

Comment: You are a star - thank you! As suggested I changed it to get_permalink. Thanks for your help

Comment: Never use `wp_is_mobile()`. It is broken at best and will not work with any cache.